# Projective representations and cental extensions based on Schottenloher's book

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory

In Schottentloher's book, a theorem is stated:

[image]

Later on, a remark is made:

[image]

My confusion comes: Is E always of the form made in the remark, namely are the following to sets equal(up to set theoretic iso)?:
\begin{equation}
\{(U,g) \in U(\mathbb{H}) \times G \,:\;\; \hat{\gamma} (U)=Tg\}=U(1) \times_{\omega} G
\end{equation}
Or does this equation hold only for $\mathbb{H}=C$?

**EDIT**: Put more precisely, according to ACouriousMind's reply:

Why is the subgroup of $U(\mathbb{H}) \times G$, which obeys that  $\hat{\gamma}(U)=Tg$ isomorphic to the semidirect product $U(1) \times_{\omega} G$?

Comment: I don't understand the question and I think you have misunderstood what the text is saying: It's defining $E$ as a *subgroup* of $U(H)\times G$ - the subgroup that obeys $\hat{\gamma}(U) = Tg$, and this subgroup is then always isomorphic to the semi-direct product in the remark. I don't know where the idea that $E$ is "of the form $U(H)\times G$" comes from.

Comment: Precisely. This is my question. You claim that the subgroup that obeys the condition you wrote is always isomorphic to the semi-direct product in the remark. Could you please explicitly write this isomorphism out?

Comment: Are they only set theoretically isomorphic,or also group theoretically isomorphic?

Comment: Did you try just spelling out the definition? The pre-image of any single element under $\hat{\gamma}$ is a $\mathrm{U}(1)$ coset just because it's the kernel of $\hat{\gamma}$. The definition of $E$ just says "all $(U,g)$ such that $U$ is in the pre-image of $Tg$". So the set-theoretic structure of $E$ as $\mathrm{U}(1)\times G$ follows immediately. That the group product inherited as a subgroup is the same as the semi-direct product from the remark is similarly just unpacking definitions (note that the "Wigner's theorem" in the remark is also just taking a pre-image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ACuriousMind said, the preimage of $Tg$ under $\hat{\gamma}$ must be a $U(1)$-coset for each $g$. So $$E =\cup_{g\in G} \{(U(1)U_g, g)\}$$  where $U_g$ is some choice of representatives for each coset.
You can then simply identify $(e^{i\phi}, g)\mapsto (e^{i\phi}U_g, g)$